# C# Jagged Array use in IronPython

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ironpython

I have this code but couldn't understand that how they defined and what is the concept behind? I guess it is Jagged Array but here they rename index but I'm not sure.

```
obj = Array[IItem]([
item.Parent["FirstName"]["LastName"], 
item.Parent["Address1"]["Address2"], 
item.Parent["EmployeeId"]["DepartmentID"]
])
```